# Infinite scroll on single.php with URL change

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll

I'm developing a theme that needs this functionality, exactly like [The Daily Beast](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/05/04/exclusive-pentagon-admits-our-anti-isis-strikes-killed-civilians.html) and [Bloomberg](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-05-04/gross-calls-bull-market-end-again-as-oxygen-running-out) does.

If you scroll the page until the end of the blogpost, the next one will be loaded and the URL will change to match the current post.

Does anyone knows a plugin or at least any ideas on how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to listen to an event which is fired when a visitor browses to the end of the page. This could be a `scroll` listener that fires when a certain element pops into view (multiple ways to do this).

When the event is fired, you'll need to fetch the new post with AJAX (see WP documentation on plugin/theme AJAX, e.g. how to use `admin-ajax.php` in WordPress). After the AJAX response is loaded and successfully inserted to the template you'll need to use the browser History API or similar to push a new URL for the page.

Maybe you could split this question into several smaller ones and get more descriptive answers on each. I see the following which you need to solve (and which aren't 1-to-1 related):

1. Trigger a JS event when user scrolls to a certain place on the page.
2. Load and insert a WordPress post to a template using AJAX.
3. Alter the browsers current URL address after something is done on the page.